# Test input without label with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I use react-testing-library in my application. Normally, to check if the input is in the form, we use getByLabelText. For example:

```
getByLabelText(/name/i)
```

But what if my input does not have any label? This is because of the design (UI) so I cannot have a label for the input. How can I check if that input exists in the form?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following to target a text input field.

```js
getByRole('textbox', {name: /name/i})
```

More info https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority

Comment: How can I know that I get the correct input? For example, my input's name is "name"

Comment: If you need to verify, you could always assign that to a variable and then use `screen.debug(variableName);`

Answer (score 2):

You can also add an aria-label to your input:

```
<TextField inputProps={{'aria-label': "example" }} />
```

and then in your test:

```
expect(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "example"})).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a test ID to the input that solely will be used for testing purposes.

```js
<input data-testid="your-id" />
```

And in your test you would do a `query` rather than `get` as `get` will fail the test if the element doesn't exist at all.

```js
expect(queryByTestId('your-id')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

Or you could search by display value to look for the input value

```js
expect(queryByDisplayValue('input-value')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know an expected text in your input, you can add "data-testid" to your input and find it like that:

```
<input data-testid="my-input"/>

const myInput = getByTestId('my-input');
```

Comment: Can I get it by the input's name? I don't think we should add data-testid to all the inputs. I have around 30 inputs in my form

Comment: As far as I remember, you can by digging through `document`. But it's a messy job.